# Insert into become very slow after adding a left join. What could be the problem?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I left join 5 tables and insert the select result into my target table,
200,000 records costed 30s before I add a new left join in the statement. However,after the addtion of the new left join,the sql statement can't finish after running for 1h. 
The new right table is still one of the previous 5 tables.

Normal sql statement：200,000 records costed 30s

```sql
insert into SCHEMA1.T_AGRGT_INFO(
50 columns...
)
select
50 columns...
from
(select * from TB1@DB) T1 --about 200,000 records
left join
(select * from SCHEMA1.TB2) T2 --about 500,000 records
on T1.COL1 = T2.COL1 
left join
(select
    COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5
from
    (select COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,
        row_number()  over(partition by COL1 BY COL2 DESC) NUM
    from SCHEMA2.TB3@DB  
) T
where T.NUM = 1) T3  --about 50,000 records
on T1.COL1 = T3.COL1 
left join
(select
    COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5
from
    (select COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,
        row_number()  over(partition by COL1 BY COL2 DESC) NUM
    from SCHEMA2.TB4   
) T
where T.NUM = 1) T4 --about 50,000 records
on T2.COL2 = T4.COL1  
left join
(select
    COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5
from
    (select COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,
        row_number()  over(partition by COL1,COL2,COL3 BY COL4 DESC) NUM
    from SCHEMA2.TB5   
) T
where T.NUM = 1) TB5    --about 50,000 records
on T2.COL2 = T5.COL1;
```

all left joins don't replicate records,the total number of records from the statement equals 'select count(*) from T1@DB'.
TB1,TB3 are accessed by dblink,TB4,TB5 are in another schema.

Abnormal statement：200,000 records can't finish after running for 1h

```sql
--all the same except for adding a left join
left join
(select
    COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5
from
    (select COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,
        row_number()  over(partition by COL1 BY COL2 DESC) NUM
    from SCHEMA2.TB4   
) T
where T.NUM = 2) T4_1   --about 15,000 records
on T2.COL2 = T4_1.COL1
```

I just added a left join by reusing TB4, the performance dropped greatly.
What could be the problem? How to solve it?

ps: Oracle DB

Comment: Your psuedo code makes this look exactly the same as the other sub query for TB4. is it? If not, are the right indexes in place?

Comment: @TomC Not exactly. In the first subquery `T.NUM = 1`, while in the new one, `T.NUM = 2`.

Comment: @TomC Yes, T4_1 is another sub query for TB4 with T.NUM = 2. In query T4 T.NUM=1

Comment: I wonder if you could avoid all those sub queries, and just make them normal joins, selecting the one row you need from by using the correct "partition by" and ordering. Just a thought - it would depend on whether that exploded the underlying data set too much. And it doesn't answer your question as to "why".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why adding second rows from t4 slows makes things slow and without data access and execution plans we can't do much, I suppose.

But there is one thing you could try. You are using the same code here, so move it to `with` clause, then join this part twice into your main query using `rn = 1` and `rn = 2`. Simplified code, without `t3` and `t5`:

```
with t4 as (
    select * 
      from (select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,
                   row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2 desc) rn
              from tb4 )
      where rn <= 2 )
select * 
    from tb1 t1                                               
    left join tb2 t2 on t2.col1 = t1.col1                     
    left join t4 t4a on t4a.col1 = t2.col2 and t4a.rn = 1    
    left join t4 t4b on t4b.col1 = t2.col2 and t4a.rn = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Sorry for not replying for so long.  The efficiency has been greatly improved when I insert the results of sub queries into temp tables and left join with these temp tables.
It costs only 40s.  Thanks.@Ponder Stibbons